# SSH login disconnect with Operation not permitted [preauth]

Tags: ssh

I have SSH server running on an Android phone under GNURoot app with image file for wheezy. The sshd -d on the phone says:

`Server listening on port 2233`

and after I try to login the connection established and then I get:

`chroot(/var/run/sshd)" Operation not permitted [preauth] 
do_cleanup [preauth] 
do_cleanup 
Killing privsep child 18597`

The ssh client on my computer says:

`Read from socket failed: Connection reset by peer`

Anybody has any idea what went wrong?

Comment: Do you have correct permission on user root directory?

Comment: Do you have /system/xbin/ash ?

Comment: I did an `apt-get install ash` and now I have `/bin/ash`. The root user's directoy is `/home/` and the permissions on it `drwxr-xr-x` owner is `root:root`. And if I try to login to this linux running on the phone the ssh client says: `Connection closed by 192.168.0.12`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use dropbear instead.

`apt-get install dropbear`

I cannot find any way to avoid chroot error, so I suggest you another ssh server. It works well. :-)

Comment: Apache2 has nothing to do with SSH.

Comment: @salivan You are correct. But the main point is - in my opinion - GNURoot not running as root, so listening port not works well.

Comment: OP has port 2233 open, no root needed.

Comment: Try my solution.

Comment: @salivan `ash` is installed into `/bin/` (debian rootfs), so I did `ln -s /bin/ash /bin/busybox` instead. But nothing changed. :-(

Comment: Maybe I forgot ln syntax, but symlink is: /system/xbin/ash and location of ash is  /system/bin/busybox

Comment: In other words, /system/xbin/ash needs to exist! And it should be pointing to ash, via busybox or whatever. (for me busybox way worked).

Comment: Try ln -s /system/bin/busybox /system/xbin/ash

Comment: @salivan ash works well in android and debian just typed `ash`. Not solved. GNURoot makes a virtual root at `/data/data/champion.gnuroot/app_install/roots/wheezy/`, so anything in `/system/` may not affects to debian.

Comment: There are many other Android server apps that are listening on a port larger than 1024 and I'm able to connect to them with a client from laptop. Many webservers, ssh servers, ftp servers. They work without any problem. Why this doesn't? I tryed to create symlink, but I got `/bin/ln: failed to create symbolic link '/system/xbin/ash': Read-only file system.` And there is no file in that directory called busybox.

Comment: @Janos `/system/` remount must be root. Try this before: `su; mount -o rw,remount /system`

Comment: Dunno why this was downvoted. @salivan's comment is completely unrelated.

Comment: @Mark check the edit history of OQ. my comments was 100% relevant to the original answer. it was down voted because at the time answer made no sense. After comments and down vote he changed answer.

Comment: Ahh, I mean answer, not comment

Answer (score 0):

Please do:

```
su
ln -s /system/bin/busybox /system/xbin/ash
```

You are getting that error because there is no shell for user root to use.

Comment: /bin/ln: failed to create symboic link `/system/xbin/ash`: Read only filesystem.
The login shell for the root user is /bin/bash and this shell exists.

Answer (score 0):

You can get past the chroot by setting UsePrivilegeSeparation=no in /etc/ssh/sshd_config, but both openssh and dropbear fail currently on my phone on the latest GNURoot Debian.

They fail with access denied from openpty, so it's a proot bug (and probably not easy to fix.)

Answer (score 0):

After setting `UsePrivilegeSeparation=no`, I was getting *password login failure*.
But I was able to work around it by adding my public key for key-based login (safer anyway).